# How to select format date using carbon?

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

How to select format date using carbon ?

I'm used format **->select(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(score_dt, '%M'))"))** before.

I want to change the format by using carbon, how do I use it in a select query? to display month name

Comment: innocent question, why do you need to format the date during select? can't you not format it after your got the field result?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?. Are you trying to get data for passing it to graph are something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of the [Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Laravel uses Carbon 2 now.

You should be able to get the month name with the `monthName` property: `$yourDateObject->monthName`.

Carbon, however, is a PHP library and is not part of the database you're using. This means you can't use it in your select query, to use Carbon, you'll need to format your data in your model/controller/frontend. This is a fairly standard way of turning ISO8601 dates into human readable form.

Comment: Can carbon be used in javascript ? for example I take the month name for the graph, how do I use it? **Month.push(data.month);**

Comment: No, Carbon is a PHP library, so can only be used in PHP.